# Snowflake - Azure File upload - How can i partition the file if size is more than 40MB

Tags: file-upload, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-blob-storage

I have to upload the data from a Snowflake table to Azure BLOB using COPYINTO command. The copy command I have is working for SINGLE = TRUE property but I want to break the in multiple files if the size exceeds 40MB.

For example, There is a table 'TEST' in snowflake with 100MB, I want to upload this data in azure BLOB.

The copy into command should create files in below format
TEST_1.csv (40MB)
TEST_2.csv (40MB)
TEST_3.csv (20MB)

--COPY INTO Command I am using
`copy into @stage/test.csv from snowflake.test file_format = (format_name = PRW_CSV_FORMAT) header=true OVERWRITE = TRUE SINGLE = TRUE max_file_size = 40000000`

Comment: Please provide the COPY INTO statement you are running to create multiple files and explain what errors/issues you are seeing when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot control the output size of file unloads, only the max file size. The number and size of the files are based on maximum performance as it parallelizes the operation. If you want to control the number/size of files, that would be a feature request. Otherwise, just work out a process outside of Snowflake to combine the files afterward. For more details about unloading, please refer to the [blog](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Best-Practices-for-Data-Unloading)